# Python Numpy: Updating multiple columns using lists failed in V1.10.1

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas 0.16.2, the following code works fine:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
             'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
             'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
             'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
             index=[0, 1, 2, 3])                     
df1[['A','B']] = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]
df1
Out[149]: 
   A  B   C   D
0  1  2  C0  D0
1  1  2  C1  D1
2  1  2  C2  D2
3  1  2  C3  D3
```

In pandas 0.17, the same code returns the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 4
```

Is this a bug with 0.17? Any solution which will work with both versions?

**Update:**
It turned out the problem is caused by numpy instead of pandas. In numpy 1.09, the lists must be [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]] while in 1.10.1 it must be [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]] for this assignment to work.

Comment: as a one liner, try this : df1[['A','B']] = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]] .

Comment: This works with 0.17 but not with 0.16.2

Comment: @Allen, I tried it with 0.16.2 on `Python2` and it works ok. Could it be the version of `numpy`? Mine is 1.10.1

Comment: Thanks, guys, it turned out the problem is caused by numpy instead of pandas.  In numpy 1.09, the lists must be [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]] while in 1.10.1 it must be [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method ( 1 )

```
In [12]:
A_values = [1,1,1,1]
B_values = [2,2,2,2]
df.assign(A = A_values , B = B_values)
Out[12]:
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   C0  D0
1   1   2   C1  D1
2   1   2   C2  D2
3   1   2   C3  D3
```

---

### Method ( 2 )

---

```
import itertools

In [10]:
A_values = [1,1,1,1]
B_values = [2,2,2,2]

In [28]:
df1[['A','B']] = zip(A_values , B_values)
df1
Out[28]:
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   C0  D0
1   1   2   C1  D1
2   1   2   C2  D2
3   1   2   C3  D3
```

Comment: Careful... you'll have to use `list(zip(...))` for Python3 compatibility

Comment: good catch I didn't try this with `python 3` anyway `list(zip(...))` will produce same result

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Sword's comment.

```
df1[['A','B']] = pd.np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]).T
```

You can get a clue about this by casting `df1` to a `pd.np.array`

```
>>> pd.np.array(df1[['A','B']])
array([['A0', 'B0'],
       ['A1', 'B1'],
       ['A2', 'B2'],
       ['A3', 'B3']], dtype=object)
```

Notice the shape is `(4,2)`